# New and Delete operator on singly linked list in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, new-operator, singly-linked-list, delete-operator

```
#include <iostream>

#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

struct node {

    int num;

    node *link;

};

int main (void) {

    node *head, *tail;

    tail = new node;

    head = tail;

    int i = 1;

    while (i < 20) {

        tail -> num = i;

        tail -> link = new node;

        assert(tail->link != NULL);

        tail = tail->link;

        i++;

    }

    tail -> num = i;

    tail -> link = head;

    for (int x = 0;x<100;x++) {

        cout<<head->num<<" ";

        head = head->link;

    }

    delete head;

    return 0;

}
```

This source code is running but I feel like the delete operator is wrong? Like out of place? It's not suppose to be head. I expect to delete all the new nodes. But how?

Comment: Please don't write `tail -> num = i;`.  Collapse it to `tail->num = i;` Ditto for all your lines where you deference a pointer with the `->` operator.

Comment: Every node you `new`, you must `delete`. `delete head` deletes only the head node. The rest...  lost forever floating in the unknown.

Comment: The `delete` statement is not wrong, but it's only going to delete that one node.    Are you expecting it to delete all of the nodes?

Comment: @user4581301 yep, however if the delete scheme is just having the node call delete on its subnode - that's good way to get into a nasty stackoverflow when the list is long enough, like a million nodes.

Comment: @user4581301 how do i delete all the 'new' nodes?

Answer (score 0):

Each `new` needs a corresponding `delete`. As you have it, you're only deleting the `head` of the list. All the other nodes will leak memory.   Also, some weirdness with that extra node you allocate at the beginning for tail.

This is closer to what you want:

```
int main (void) {

    node *head, *tail;

    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;

    int i = 1;

    // allocate 20 nodes into a list
    while (i < 20) {

        node* newNode = new node();
        newNode->num = i;
        newNode->link = nullptr;

        if (head == nullptr) {
           head = newNode;
           tail = newNode;
        } else {
           tail->link = newNode;
        }
        i++;
    }

    // print all the nodes out
    node* probe = head;
    while (probe) {
       cout << probe->num << " ";
       probe = probe->next;
    }

    // delete all the nodes in the list
    probe = head;
    while (probe) {
       node* n = probe;
       probe = probe->link;
       delete n;
    }

    // don't leave invalid state
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Well, I actually expect to delete all the new nodes.

Comment: @ZephyrLeone That is exactly what the final loop is doing

Comment: The OP code was a circular linked list.  Not sure if that was desired or accidental.